# GraphicsContextBase instance has no attribute 'get_sketch_params'

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder

Quite new to python and programming and tried to search for answers to `matplotlib` plots, but couldn't find answers to my question.

I use Spyder and have anaconda installed. Installed matplotlib but when i run simple plot commands I just get `<"matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x11090c18">` and no plot

If I run it in a dedicated python interpreter i just get an empty plot

The simple code is:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [2,4,6,8,10])
plt.show()
```

Is this just the result of some stupid error I made in the installation process?

Hope someone can help med out

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you're seeing is generated by a change the Matplotlib team did some months ago. I tried to fix it in Spyder 2.3.0/1 but maybe it's not working correctly.

To see a plot the code you need to run is

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [2,4,6,8,10])
plt.show()
```

Notice the second line, that's what's needed to get interactive plots.